# Repeating the elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays

How can I repeat the elements of an array in Java?

For example, given the array `{a,b,c,d,e,f}` and a number `n`, I want to produce an `n`-element array that looks like `{a,b,c,d,e,f,a,b,c,d,e,f,a,b,c,...}`.

If I knew the length of the input and output arrays in advance, I could just write something like this:

```
int a=input[0], b=input[1], c=input[2], d=input[3], e=input[4], f=input[5];

int[] array = new int[n];
array[0]=a; array[1]=b; array[2]=c; array[3]=d; array[4]=e; array[5]=f;
array[6]=a; array[7]=b; array[8]=c; array[9]=d; array[10]=e; array[11]=f;
array[12]=a; array[13]=b; array[14]=c; // .. and so on
```

But how can I do this if I don't know the lengths yet?  I assume I would have to use a loop of some kind, but I'm not sure how to write one.  Or is there some built-in way to repeat an array in Java, like some other languages have?

Comment: what you want to ask from our end..??

Comment: Have you tried using an indexed `for` loop? As in `for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { System.out.println ("array[" + i + "] = " + array[i]); }`

Comment: For those who voted to close this question (e.g. @Pshemo ) : I'm confused now. **How should this question be stated in order to be NOT off-topic?**. I know there are [some discussions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215596/). And I also think that the question should contain infos e.g. about the type of the array. But how should a question about **how to create an array with size x that contains the contents of a given array repeatedly** be stated? Would it be OK if he had written a `for`-loop and asked for alternatives? Of if he asked about performance? Or how to do it with streams?

Comment: @Marco13 IMO general questions are OK. But I see trivial code writing requests (and this question is one of them, since usage of modulo operator or creating method which can simulate it is not very hard) as "give me teh codes" questions, which I don't support. I think that in their case we can apply 3rd rule about *homework questions* from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic which is why I cast my close vote. I wouldn't do it if question contained proof of effort like "I tried (code) but got foo instead of bar. I think problem may be with ... but I don't know how to solve it.".

Comment: @Marco13 Also I have nothing against answers posted here. They are correct and only possible problem with them is that they may encourage more bad questions. It was always risky to post answers to bad questions because community don't like such behavior, but if answer author thinks that (s)he did right thing then few down-votes shouldn't discourage him/her. Also if you think that this question doesn't deserve to be closed feel free to cast reopen vote. I can't stop you and I don't want to, do as you believe is right. It is community that shapes what SO is and casting votes is big part of it.

Comment: @chandu061 Do you mind if I reword the question in a way that (I think) it could be considered as a "good" question? (If you referred to a particular array type, like `int[]` or `String[]`, it would be good to know it. Otherwise, I could still try to write it generically.

Comment: @Pshemo As already mentioned on meta: While a solution to the stated problem is trivial ("Just use %"), there are different options - as can be seen by the vastly different answers. And all of them have advantages and distadvantages. E.g. I'm pretty sure that the solution by "Flown" is faster than the %-solution (although this would have to be verified). I think asking for these options and their pros/cons is a *good* thing (to see a bigger picture, and maybe question the way that "one has been doing this for years")

Comment: @Marco13 True, but that would apply if OP would explicitly ask for *different* solutions, their advantages or disadvantages, for instance because he finds `%` too slow or because on interview `%` wasn't accepted. But currently question asks for *any* solution. I agree that while *problem* it describes may be interesting, the question looks *bad*. It probably can be improved and changed into good question, but it would mean that we will change it into *different* question than what OP asked (just like any *give me teh codes* can be rewritten into something nice). I judged question, not problem.

Comment: @Pshemo I see, well, this one is lost nevertheless, it will not come back to something positive from -10 (and any "significant" modification would invalidate the existing answers), so let's just leave it as it is.

Comment: @Marco13: It might yet come back, because of the meta effect. Anyway, while I agree that this is a trivial question, that does not make it invalid or useless. Sure, any *experienced* programmer knows that the obvious answer is "use `%`", but there must be millions of beginner Java programmers out there who don't (yet) know that. It's a valid and useful question that (based on a quick Google search) does not appear to have a good answer elsewhere on SO yet; accordingly, I've voted to reopen it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen The question may be "trivial" (and there's a discussion on meta, including the differentiation between "trivial" questions and "crap" questions - still lacking a strict definition of either of them, but hey, let's just discuss a little... (rolls eyes)). But even for this seemingly trivial question, there's at least the aspect of *performance* (see Flown's answer). If the asker had asked for performance in particular, he might already have 18 *upvotes* instead of 18 *downvotes*. (But then, the question would have not ended on meta, so the meta effect has to be subtracted)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen you have __changed__ the question and __greatly__ edited it. As it stands, it's a perfectly fine question it's just a _different_ question. I'm not sure I feel easy about changing it so much just to reopen it.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen link to meta thread? That's just common courtesy.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I tried to rephrase it the way I understood it, and the way most of the answerers seem to have understood it. Of course, the author of the question, if they're still around, is free to edit it further if they think I've distorted it somehow. Anyway, the earlier version of the question was deleted; I'd say even the most heavy-handed edit still preserves more of the original question than outright deletion. (And the meta thread is [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305353/serial-downvoting-of-one-question-and-its-answers).)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I agree, I just feel like it would be better to ask the question again (not as OP, and clearly written). Undelete this one and then move the answers there and close this as a duplicate of the good question.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: That would certainly be an option, but -- unless the OP actively objects to my rewrite -- it seems a lot of work for what is almost the same result in the end. I might get a bit of extra rep out of it, but it's not like I need it.

Comment: I don't know, this sort of creative Liberty is usually not allowed for non CW posts. Then again in this case OP has probably already left us and doesn't care :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Probably; and, as I noted, they can always revert the edit if they don't like it. I suppose my approach to editing has always been a bit Wikipedia-ish: "[be bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Be_bold), but never [edit war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Edit_warring)." Also, IME, one can usually get away with quite a bit of "creative" editing, as long as the result of the edit is a genuine improvement. Yes, it's a bit risky, but in the end, most people won't object to their posts being made better, as long as they can really agree that it *is* better.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I rephrased this question and answered it in a more detailed way. See my edit in my answer.

Answer (score 42):

This implementation is much cleaner and faster than the others shown here.

```
public static <T> T[] repeat(T[] arr, int newLength) {
    T[] dup = Arrays.copyOf(arr, newLength);
    for (int last = arr.length; last != 0 && last < newLength; last <<= 1) {
        System.arraycopy(dup, 0, dup, last, Math.min(last << 1, newLength) - last);
    }
    return dup;
}
```

## Theory

`System.arraycopy` is a native call. Therefore it is very fast but it doesn't mean it is the fastest way.

Every other solution copys the array element by element. My solution copys larger blocks. Every iteration duplicates the existing elements in the array which means the loop will run at most **log2(n)** times.

## Profiling reports

Here is my benchmark code to reproduce the results:

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.BenchmarkMode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Fork;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Measurement;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Mode;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.OutputTimeUnit;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.State;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Threads;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Warmup;

@Fork(3)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@Threads(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
public class MyBenchmark {

  private static final String[] TEST_ARRAY = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
  private static final int NEW_LENGTH = 10_000;

  @Benchmark
  public String[] testMethod() {
    String[] dup = Arrays.copyOf(TEST_ARRAY, NEW_LENGTH);
    for (int last = TEST_ARRAY.length; last != 0 && last < NEW_LENGTH; last <<= 1) {
      System.arraycopy(dup, 0, dup, last, Math.min(last << 1, NEW_LENGTH) - last);
    }
    return dup;
  }

  @Benchmark
  public String[] testMethod1() {
    String[] arr = new String[NEW_LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < NEW_LENGTH; i++) {
      arr[i] = TEST_ARRAY[i % TEST_ARRAY.length];
    }
    return arr;
  }

  @Benchmark
  public String[] testMethod2() {
    List<String> initialLetters = Arrays.asList(TEST_ARRAY);
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    int indexOfLetterToAdd = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      results.add(initialLetters.get(indexOfLetterToAdd++));
      if (indexOfLetterToAdd == initialLetters.size()) {
        indexOfLetterToAdd = 0;
      }
    }
    return results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public String[] testMethod3() {
    String result[] = new String[NEW_LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < NEW_LENGTH && j < TEST_ARRAY.length; i++, j++) {
      result[i] = TEST_ARRAY[j];
      if (j == TEST_ARRAY.length - 1) {
        j = -1;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Benchmark
  public String[] testMethod4() {
    String[] result = Stream.iterate(TEST_ARRAY, x -> x).flatMap(x -> Stream.of(TEST_ARRAY)).limit(NEW_LENGTH)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
    return result;
  }
}
```

### Results

```
Benchmark                Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testMethod   avgt   30   4154,553 ±   11,242  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testMethod1  avgt   30  19273,717 ±  235,547  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testMethod2  avgt   30  71079,139 ± 2686,136  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testMethod3  avgt   30  18307,368 ±  202,520  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testMethod4  avgt   30  68898,278 ± 2488,104  ns/op
```

### EDIT

I rephrased this question and answered it with more precise benchmarks as it was suggested.
[Fastest way to create new array with length N and fill it by repeating a given array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32452025/4105457)

Comment: Is bigger or smaller score better ?

Comment: This question has already one deletion vote, so it may end up being deleted. If I ware you I would probably save this post and if question will end being deleted create separate self answered question in which you will use this post as answer (or as base of new answer). You could also provide in new question link to deleted question explaining that you are sharing knowledge.

Comment: @Flown I had already put this on my "todo list": Re-write the question in a (hopefully) better form, and provide a comparison of the options, measured with JMH. Now this is obsolete, but as Pshemo said: You should probably create a backup of this post for when the question is deleted (and maybe create your own question and add this as an answer - mabe even extended a little for different input/output array sizes, e.g. 10,1000 and 100000 input elements times 100, 10000, 10000000 output elements. (Yes, I know, the JMH run will take forever ;-) but it could be interesting)

Comment: @Marco13 if i have time in the near future and this post will be deleted i'll make my own question and provide some extended benchmarks as suggested. Should i provide more information?

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful A smaller score is better because the measurement mode is average.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I think the important thing here is the `Units` part, which is `ns/op` = "nanoseconds per operation". The lower, the better. (There are other units where a *higher* score is better, e.g. `ops/ms` = "operations per millisecond").

Comment: This solution is very slick. However, it is worth asking the question, "Do i have such a need performance that i couldn't refactor out a couple variables in order to help readability and maintenance a bit?" The algorithm is already optimized to perform block memory operations.

Comment: @NathanKummer Well IMHO it is easily readable. How would you improve this snippet?

Comment: Unformatted code...
 static final int ZERO_INDEX = 0;
 public static <T> T[] repeat(T[] arr, int newLength) {
     T[] dup = Arrays.copyOf(arr, newLength);
     boolean isArrayContainsData = arr.length != 0;
     for (int startIndexForCopy = arr.length; isArrayContainsData && startIndexForCopy < newLength; startIndexForCopy *= 2) {
         int elementCountAfterNextCopy = Math.min(startIndexForCopy * 2, newLength);
   int elementsToCopy = elementCountAfterNextCopy - startIndexForCopy;
   System.arraycopy(dup, ZERO_INDEX, dup, startIndexForCopy, elementsToCopy);
     }
     return dup;
 }

Comment: I replaced the bit-shift operations with mutliplication and I assigned the result of each operation to a local variable named to show its purpose. I realize that code style is largely a matter of personal style and preference, but I would prefer to find what I just posted, even though I would expect it to perform slightly more slowly in a race.

Comment: I looked at your code and it is a way more descriptive but seems more distracting to me because of the long variable names. Though it depends as you said on someones coding style.

Comment: Like I said, I'm a big fan of your solution, and I didn't have any trouble understanding it, though I did have to stop and think for a minute. I was thinking largely in terms of "how likely is somebody else to come in and screw it up?" I think that the variable names that reflect the purpose of the operation helps the code to stay not broken, when someone else decides that they need to do something with it. But I like your solution. I was going to just repeat the first array copy until I filled the second array, but I didn't think to use the growing destination as a source to copy from.

Answer (score 9):

I am assuming you know the size of the input, (e.g. you know that there are six elements in the input above. Let us name it `iSize`. Alternatively, you could find this using `arr.length` where `arr` is the input array.)

This might be a cleaner solution for the above.

```
for(int i=iSize; i<10000; i++)
    arr[i] = arr[i%iSize];
```

Comment: You forgot to copy over the first iSize elements :) But this, if corrected, is the "easy to understand" code. Maye explain what % does to OP, as he seem to be a novice.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia, since I am filling in the same array, I do not need to copy the first `iSize` elements since they already exist in that array.

Comment: I think he wants a new array, not as in the first is longer than the mask

Answer (score 7):

You can try like this

```
String arr[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
int repeat = 10000;
String result[] = new String[repeat];
for(int i=0, j=0; i<repeat && j<arr.length; i++, j++)
{
   result[i] = arr[j];
   if(j == arr.length -1)
         j = -1;
   System.out.println("array["+i+"] : "+result[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
List<String> initialLetters = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f");
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
int indexOfLetterToAdd = 0;
for (int i=1;i<10000;i++){
    results.add(initialLetters.get(indexOfLetterToAdd++));
    if(indexOfLetterToAdd==initialLetters.size()){ //reset counter when necessary
        indexOfLetterToAdd=0;
    }
}
return results;
```

Answer (score 4):

A very clean and fast implementation is like this with a little expanded and much readable form:

```
public static String[] nLenArry(String[] inpArry, int n) {
    String[] output = new String[n];
    int length = inpArry.length;
    int position = 0;

    // Copy Iterations
    while (position < n-length) {
        System.arraycopy(inpArry, 0, output, position, length);
        position += length;
    }

    // Copy the last part
    System.arraycopy(inpArry, 0, output, position, n % length);

    return output;
}
```

---

Same code in more compact form:

```
public static String[] nLenArry(String[] inpArry, int n) {
    String[] output = new String[n];
    int position = 0;
    while (position < n - inpArry.length) {
        System.arraycopy(inpArry, 0, output, position, inpArry.length);
        position+=inpArry.length;
    }
    System.arraycopy(inpArry, 0, output, position, n % inpArry.length);
    return output;
}
```

---

Also, if you want to save some space, you can use this clever little trick and try implementing it as a new class:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;

public class RepeatedArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
    private E[] arry;
    private int size;

    public RepeatedArrayList(E[] inpArry, int size) {
        this.arry = inpArry;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public E get(int position) {
        if (position >= 0 && position < size)
            return arry[position % arry.length];
        else throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(
            "index " + position + " is negative or >= " + size
        );
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.size;
    }
}
```

After this all you need to do is the following code in your other classes

```
repeatedArry cst = new RepeatedArrayList(arr, 10000);
```

and

```
//use
cst.get(x);

//instead of 
arr[x];
```

Comment: I think your last example (the ArrayList subclass) needs to override several more methods to really get a consistent List implementation. (For one thing, I'm not sure what .size() will return for your class, but it surely won't be correct.) Also, if the OP really needs an array instead of a List (e.g. to pass to an API that expects an array), this obviously won't work. The idea is clever, though.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thank you for pointing the mistake with `.size()` it should be correct now. Also yes some other methods also needed to be overwritten like `.toString()` and `.hashCode()`. I actually wanted to give a general idea about it if it can be used.

Comment: I was actually thinking more about things like iterators and .add() (which really should throw an exception). But actually, it turns out you can get all that stuff automatically done for you if you extend [AbstractList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) instead of ArrayList; see edit above.

Answer (score 4):

This should help:

```
static int[] function(int[] array, int n)
{
    if(array == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    if(n < 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    int[] newArray = new int[n];
    int arraysize = array.length;
    int i = 0 , j = 0;

    int loop = n -  (n % arraysize);

    while(i < loop)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < arraysize; j++, i++)
        {
            newArray[i] = array[j];
        }
    }

    j = 0;
    while(i < n)
    {
        newArray[i++] = array[j++]; 
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

same answer in another didactic form, without specific function on array

```
// INPUT
int[] input={1,2,3,4,5,6}; // new int[6];
int n=10;

// original size: you get it her
int size=input.length;

// final size : original size X repetition
int final_size=size*n;

int[] final_array=new int[final_size];

// we just copy in a loop, with % (modulus function)
for (int pos=0;pos<final_size;pos++)
    final_array[pos]=input[pos%size];

// OUTPUT : that's it
// => final_array
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume that your `n` is known and your array is a primitive type and not an object (e.g. List)

```
int fLen = input.length * n;
int[] outputArray = new int[fLen];
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.arraycopy(input, 0, outputArray, i * input.length, input.length);
}
```

`fLen` is the final length of your output array

Assume you don't know `n`

```
int[] outputArray2 = new int[input.length]; // at least can contain input once
System.arraycopy(input, 0, outputArray2, 0, input.length);
System.out.print("More? > (Y/N) ");
String ans = System.console().readLine();
while ( ans.equals("Y") || ans.equals("y") ) {
    int[] tmp = new int[outputArray2.length + input.length];
    System.arraycopy(outputArray2, 0, tmp, 0, outputArray2.length);
    System.arraycopy(input, 0, tmp, outputArray2.length, input.length);
    outputArray2 = tmp;
    System.out.print("More? > (Y/N) ");
    ans = System.console().readLine();
}

for ( int i = 0; i < outputArray2.length;i++)
    System.out.println("["+i+"] => " + outputArray2[i]);
```

Then you can use the outputArray as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that others have implemented similar solutions as I (using lists, but not ArrayLists), but here is how I would approach the problem. My Java is a little rusty, so I'm sure there are faster ways to do this, but here we go:

```
   char[] array = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
    ArrayList<Character> arrList = new ArrayList<Character>();

    System.out.println("How many elements in the new array?");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = kb.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        arrList.add(array[i%(array.length)]);
    }

    char[] finalArray = new char[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        finalArray[i] = arrList.get(i);
    }

    System.out.println(finalArray);
```

Basically what I am doing is getting input as to how long the resultant array should be and then appending the elements of the original array to an ArrayList that many times. The data types could be changed to work for any other data type, but since the question used chars in the array that's how I did mine. Also, if you were okay with ending with an ArrayList instead of an array, you could drop the last for() loop.

After running this, my console displays:

```
How many elements in the new array?
10
abcdefabcd
```

If you don't know the input array size before the program runs, I would first implement it as an ArrayList so that it can be dynamically grown. Then, once the user stops entering new values for the input array, it could be converted to an array (unnecessary unless you NEED the array data type instead of an ArrayList) or it can be used as is. After that you can use the same idea as above to create the output array. Code example as follows:

```
   ArrayList<Character> inputArr = new ArrayList<Character>();
    ArrayList<Character> arrList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many elements in the new array?");
    int length = kb.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter a value? (y/n): ");

    while(kb.next().equals("y")){
        System.out.print("Enter the value: ");
        inputArr.add(kb.next().charAt(0)); //in case the user inputs more than a char, only accepts the first char of the line
        System.out.print("Enter another value? (y/n): ");
    }
    System.out.println(inputArr);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        arrList.add(inputArr.get(i%(inputArr.size())));
    }

    System.out.println(arrList);
```

Comment: This ought to work, but I don't see what's the point in turning the array into an ArrayList and then converting it back into an array, when just using plain arrays would be simpler (and more efficient).

Comment: I acknowledged that this is probably not the most efficient way to solve the problem in my first paragraph. However, I chose to use ArrayLists because they can grow dynamically whereas regular arrays cannot. Since the original question said that the lengths are not known yet, I tried to make the program as general as possible. If that meant simply that the length would be input later, there are much easier ways to do this with regular arrays. However, if that meant that each element would be entered and then the program had to figure out the length, you cannot do that with regular arrays.